# MQTT is not working with .Net 6 in Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows, proxy, mqtt, .net-6.0

We are working on a .Net 6.0 application which is listening for MQTT notifications.

We are using MQTTnet library for this in client side. https://www.nuget.org/packages/MQTTnet/

Our all communction to the  server is via a proxy server.

While MQTT client is trying to connect with the server via proxy in a WIndows 10 system, its not happening.

```
 var mqttClientOptionBuilder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                           .WithCleanSession(true)
                           .WithWebSocketServer(MqttConstant.BrokerUrl, websocketparameters)
                           //.WithCredentials("proxy", "#welcome123")
                           .WithClientId(MqttConstant.HSDPId)
                           .WithProtocolVersion(MQTTnet.Formatter.MqttProtocolVersion.V311)
                           .WithKeepAlivePeriod(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 30))
                           .WithWillDelayInterval(1000)
                           .WithProxy(@"http://10.85.19.98:8080", "proxy", "#welcome123", null, true, null)                           
                           .Build();

                mqttClient.ConnectedAsync += MqttClient_ConnectedAsync;
                mqttClient.DisconnectedAsync += MqttClient_DisconnectedAsync;
                mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync += MqttClient_ApplicationMessageReceivedAsync;
                ICollection<MqttTopicFilter> topicFilterBuilders = new List<MqttTopicFilter>();
                MqttTopicFilter mqttTopicFilter = new MqttTopicFilter();
                mqttTopicFilter.Topic = "client-test/crl/things/cf488384-61b4-41d2-b7cc-68ce00e58351/cmd/receive/notified";

                mqttTopicFilter.QualityOfServiceLevel = MqttQualityOfServiceLevel.AtLeastOnce;

                topicFilterBuilders.Add(mqttTopicFilter);

                mqttClient.ConnectAsync(mqttClientOptionBuilder).Wait();
                mqttClient.SubscribeAsync(mqttTopicFilter).Wait();
```

Beauty here is, same code is working in a Linux system.

Any responses will be much appreciated.

We tried in Linux with same code and its working fine

Comment: "is trying to connect" - can you please provide some more info on how this is failing (i.e. add some logging).

Comment: ConnectAsync call is getting hanged. Call is not going only